# Stuck with syntax in c - pointers

Tags: c, syntax, pointers

If we have a `char *hello` - and the string is `"hello"`

and i do

```
char *ptr;
ptr = hello;
```

then ptr will be pointing at `'h'`, correct?

Now I have just done an assignmnet in this and completed it using the following terms

if i wanted to move the pointer to the next chatachter i would just do `ptr++`. If i wanted to use the value of the pointer for some check, i would use `if(*ptr == '\0')...`

When i was doing the assignmnets our teacher gave us some pre built methods, and they used stuff like

```
*string++ = *s++;
```

ok, so why would we want to do `*string` (which gets a value) - and combine it with `++`

I hope i make sense in explaining what is not clear. Its just I managed to do the whole assignment with ptr++ to move to next element or *ptr to check its value

Comment: @leo I assumed `"hello"` is a character literal, so I put it inside quotes. If it is a variable name, the quotes are of course not needed (but then your first question doesn't make much sense).

Comment: just tried to edit it to make more sence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiom `*s++` means "take the value pointed to, and switch to the next one".
This way you can do your check operations in a loop. The assignment `*p++ = *q++` copies the value of `*q` to the place pointed by `p`, and shifts both `p` and `q` to the next place, so the next time you execute `*p++ = *q++` the next character will be copied behind the first one. And so on.

Comment: @Vlad, you had your p/q round the wrong way. Hope you don't mind the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. In your original question, `ptr` would be set to point to the same first character as `hello`, which may *not necessarily* be `h`. You may have done:

```
char *hello = "goodbye";
```

in which case both `hello` and `ptr` will point to that `g`. However your edit now makes it clear that you meant:

```
char *hello = "hello";
```

Your comment on `ptr++` is correct. It will move `ptr` so that it points to the next character and, as per C string handling convention, `'\0'` marks the end of the string.

The statement:

```
*string++ = *s++;
```

is something you often see in string copying code (copying `s` to `string`), something like:

```
char *mystrcpy (char *d, char *s) {
    char *d2 = d;
    while (*s != '\0')
        *d2++ = *s++;
    *d2 = '\0';
    return d;
}
```

In this case, the line `*d2++ = *s++;` means:

- copy the character at `s` to the memory location `d2`.
- increment `d2` to point to the next destination character.
- increment `s` to point to the next source character.

In other words,

```
*string++ = *s++;
```

is functionally identical to:

```
*string = *s;
string++;
s++;
```

Comment: made a mistake - i wanted a *char called hello which represented the string "hello"

Answer (score 1):

> so why would we want to do *string(which gets a value) - and combine it with ++

When `*string` is on the left hand side of the equals, it doesn't get the value, it **sets** the value.

The statement `*string++ = *s++;` is equivalent to:

```
*string = *s;
s++;
string++;
```

This is because `x++` is the [postfix increment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx) (as opposed to `++x` which is the prefix increment operator). The pointer x is updated but the value that `x` was originally pointing to is used in the expression.

Personally I'd say that the one-liner is more confusing to read and you should generally try to avoid complex expressions with side-effects. But in this case it's a fairly standard idiom in C, so you might as well get used to it.

Comment: so i can achieve the same results with my broken down stages version ?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to do it all on one-line - you can split it up. But you need to be very careful to understand how the pre- and postfix increment operators work when dealing with this type of code. It's easy to make an error.

Comment: thanks Mark, i am working hard at this to understand it, at least the C module is more understandable than the Haskell one :D

Answer (score 0):

> then ptr will be pointing at h, correct?

<del>Yes.</del> No. See [@paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305805/stuck-with-syntax-in-c-pointers/2305813#2305813).

> `*string++ = *s++;`

This statement can be viewed as

```
*string = *s;
string ++;
s ++;
```

That means:

1. Copy the character in `s` to the location pointed by `string`.
2. Move both `s` and `string` to the next character.

Answer (score 0):

> then ptr will be pointing at h, correct?

Yes, correct.

> ok, so why would we want to do *string(which gets a value)

The '*' doesn't necessarily get a value: it may set a value, depending on which side of the '=' sign it is.

```
char *ptr;
ptr = "hello";
char firstLetter = *ptr; //get the value: now firstLetter contains 'h'
*ptr = 'w'; //set the value: now ptr is pointing to "wello".
```

Combining * with ++ means that you do one after the other:

- On the right-hand side, '*s++' means "get the value to which s is pointing, and then increment the s pointer".
- On the left-hand side, '*string++' means "set the value to which string is pointing, and then increment the string pointer".

Combining them into a single statement simply a shorter, more compact (but functionally equivalent) way to write:

```
*string = *s;
string++;
s++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to Mark Byers' answer, who correctly points out the postfix increment ("a++") as opposed to the prefix increment ("++a").

You probably want to have a look at the [C operator precedence](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html) for the order in which operators are handled in an expression.

You can always force the precedence you want by using parentheses: (a + b) * c != a + b * c.